# Video Encoding Settings

Tags: android, video, video-encoding

Hi I was wondering if anyone could advise on what are the best encoding settings for video to be viewed on devices like the Nexus One, Desire, Desire HD and the Galaxy Tab.

What resolution should the video be?

What is the maximum file size for use over mobile networks and WiFi (Film Trailers and Music Videos)?

What format H.264, MPEG 4?

What audio frequency?

What bitrate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page may be of interest to you:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Cheers, it came in handy. Also found a good transcoder called Handbrake. http://handbrake.fr/